# Does Hibernate read domain object instance field directly or uses getter method while saving?

Tags: grails

I am on grails 3.3.6, Gorm 6 and Hibernate 5.x and observing that a domain object instance field is read directly instead of from a getter method if present while saving. for e.g.

instance field
String accountStatus is read directly instead of invoking getAccountStatus().

Can someone confirm this

Thanks
Shiraz

Comment: It's possible, sure.   If you have code that needs to compute values (like you would in getAccountStatus, I'm guessing), you can use a beforeUpdate or beforeInsert event: http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#eventsAutoTimestamping

Answer (score 0):

According to Groovy documentation:
In Groovy, getters and setters form what we call a "property", and offers a shortcut notation for accessing and setting such properties. The getters and setters are generated dynamically by the compiler. Unless you want to override the defaults, then you can, of course, customise your own:

```
instance.accountStatus
//Groovy's syntax for:
instance.getAccountStatus()
```

[Using getter and setters in grails or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547563/using-getter-and-setters-in-grails-or-not)